# Wordpress plugin for protected forums?

Tags: wordpress, forum, protected

I would like to create a forum using Wordpress.

The forum needs to password protected to only allow certain users to access the forum.
And the users will have different permissions, all users would be allowed to post but only after an admin has verified their post.

Anyone have experience with a plugin like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create private forums with this plugin for wordpress, http://simple-press.com/